# MVC Grid display another value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In the view, I have:

```
grid.Column("Complete", header: "Verified", format:  (item) => @Html.Raw(item.Complete))
```

item.complete is an integer. I created an extension method to help display  the corresponding string value since there are only 3 possibilities.
Here is the extension method:

```
   public static string CompleteValue(this int value)
    {

        switch (value)
        {
            case 0:
                return "Submitted";
            case 1:
                return "Verified - Incomplete";
            case 2:
                return "Verified - Complete";
        }
        //Default if we get this far
        return "Submitted";
    }
```

I don't know how to write the Razor code to make it work. I have tried putting the ".CompleteValue" several places in the code but nothing works.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Edit: This is the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<SendMailwithAttachment.Models.MailModel>
@using System.Activities.Statements
@using Hazards
@using SendMailwithAttachment.Models;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>My Hazards</h2>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
@{

    var dataContext = new HazardsDataContext();

    var getHazards1 = from m in dataContext.Mail
                     where (m.User == User.Identity.Name)
                     select new{m.casenum,m.ID,m.User,m.Date,m.To,m.name,m.Hazard,m.PictureDataAsByte,
                         m.Risk,m.AfterPicture,m.status,m.Complete};

    var getHazards = from n in getHazards1
        orderby n.Complete  // Order by the Completed (or Verified Status so that verified reports show up last)
        select n;

    var grid = new WebGrid(source: getHazards);

    if (getHazards.Count() > 0)
    {     

        @grid.GetHtml(columns: new[] {
        grid.Column("Casenum", header: "Case #"),
        grid.Column("Date", header: "Date"),
        grid.Column("Hazard", header: "Hazard"),
        grid.Column("Before",header: "Before",format:
        @<Text><img src="@Url.Content(item.PictureDataAsByte)" width="175" height="175" />
        </text>),
        grid.Column("Risk", header: "Risk"),
        grid.Column("After",header: "After",format:
        @<Text><img src="@Url.Content(item.AfterPicture)" width="175" height="175" />
        </Text>),
        grid.Column("status", header: "Status"),
        //grid.Column("Complete", header: "Verified", format:(item) => (item.Complete))
        grid.Column("Complete", header: "Verified", format:  (item) => @Html.CompleteValue(item.Complete))
        //grid.Column("Complete", header: "Verified", format: (item) => @Html.Raw("<input type='checkbox' " + ((item.Complete==0) ? "checked" : "") + " disabled='disabled' />")),

})

     }
    else
    {
  @Html.Raw("No Data Found")
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to create an HTMLHelper extension?

Comment: That would be fine.  I just dont know how to approach this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the namespace, C# needs this to pick up the extension.

```
using My.Namescape.ExtensionClass;
```

Put it right up on top of the Razor. Alternatively, you can add it to the `Web.config` file inside the Views folder. This way it is available to all Razor views.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write the Razor code, if you create an HTMLHelper for it. This helper can be used as many times as you want. So you don't have to add that to your view every time.

The class I think you should add, will look as follow:

```
public static class MVCHelpers
{
    public static MvcHtmlString CompleteValue(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, int value)
    {
        //create the html helper
        var builder = new TagBuilder("text");
        //Check value
        switch (value)
        {
            case 0:
                builder.SetInnerText("Submitted");
                break;
            case 1:
                builder.SetInnerText("Verified - Incomplete");
                break;
            case 2:
                builder.setInnerText("Verified - Complete");
                break;
            default:
                builder.setInnerText("Submitted");
        }
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    }
}
```

So now we created the HTMLHelper, lets go to the view.
Added the following code to the top of your view:

```
@namespace YourNameSpace
```

Or if you want the HTMLHelper to be available to all your views, insert following line in your web.config:

```
<add namespace="YourNameSpace" />
```

Now change following line in your view:

```
grid.Column("Complete", header: "Verified", format:  (item) => @Html.Raw(item.Complete))
```

To:

```
grid.Column("Complete", header: "Verified", format:  (item) => @Html.CompleteValue(item.Complete))
```

You have now created your own HTMLHelper. I hope this solves your question. If you have more questions on how to get this to work. Please ask:)

Note: I typed this code without an IDE, so there could be some syntax errors in it.

Comment: We might be closer. But here is the error I get:  Compiler Error Message: CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SendMailwithAttachment.Models.MailModel>>' has no applicable method named 'CompleteValue' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

Comment: Also, the setInnerText is SetInnerText for anyone that is using this answer.

Comment: @SDanks I changed setInnerText to SetInnerText, have been programming in Java for the last few weeks. What code is giving you the error of your first comment?

Comment: When it tries to run, it it gets a runtime error because the grid.column line has the @Html.CompleteValue underlined in red (at design time) and when I hover over it, it says Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched.  I have no clue what it is saying.  I changed the var to TagBuilder but that didnt help so I am at a loss to know how to even troubleshoot it. What are the dynamic arguments that the above error refers to?

Comment: @SDanks I get the feeling something goes wrong in the View, the Model or your controller, could you post the method in the Controller that is being called and all code from your view?

Comment: I updated the original description because the comments would not allow that many characters.

Comment: Update: If I manually create a table with the the @Html.Raw("<table") and all the elements and then use a foreach loop with the @Html.CompleteValue, it works. I had to change the extension method return to .normal enstead of .SelfClosing, but even then it appears to still be a problem with the grid. Maybe because I new up the columns as I go? Anyway, I would like to see if I can still make it work with the grid if you have any ideas why it doesnt.  Thanks.

Comment: @SDanks Good to hear. I will investigate further in about an hour.

Comment: @SDanks Do you still get an error, or is it just the HTML that is ruining your table? If it is just ruined HTML, could you run your application, use F12 (In Chrome) and copy the HTML that your view generated, so we can find the syntax problem?

Comment: When I am trying to use the grid, the word CompleteValue is underlined (at design time)and when I hover over it, it says that Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. But this does not happen if I create each table element.  It has something to do with the grid I am almost certain. Maybe it is because I create the columns with the "new" keyword and that is the dynamic content? I dont know.

Comment: Thank you for all your help.  I was able to get it working by defining a static function.  It is based on the following article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/787320/An-Absolute-Beginners-Tutorial-on-HTML-Helpers-and

Comment: @SDanks Good to hear:)